# Can a Redux action affect multiple parts of the state tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, redux

What is the consensus on an action affecting multiple parts of the state tree in Redux?

For example:

```
const ADD_POST = 'POST/ADD';

function postsReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    // switch ...
    case ADD_POST:
        return {
            ...state,
            ...action.result.post
        }
}

function anotherReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    // switch ...
    case ADD_POST:
        return {
            ...state,
            post_id: action.result.post.id
        }
}
```

I'm seeking advice on:

**Actions affecting multiple parts of the redux store/state**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. It’s the whole reason why actions exist: to separate what happened from the component’s point of view from what actually happens in terms of state change.

Comment: Thank you! This concept really helps me normalise my state structure. Have been getting suggesting as to nest reducers, I just felt that added n complexity for no gain

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's ok. If that's what you want to happen.

Comment: Can you elaborate? it seems ok to me. Im trying to avoid "nested reducers" pattern that i see some people suggesting and implying. Nested reducers seem so so so complex.

Comment: Yes, it seems fine. If you do want to apply your action to only one part of the state tree, and yet use the same reducer for different parts, you will need some way of achieving this. What you describe is what happens by default.

Comment: Its crazy to think that all reducers are are invoked every state change. Seems CPU intensive

Comment: Also there’s nothing complex about nested reducers. It’s a very natural pattern, and if you use `combineReducers` you are *already* using it :-). I suggest watching [my free course](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux) where I explain reducer composition, as well as some other topics.